# How to change the pytorch version in Google colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I need to change the pytorch version in google colab,so i install anaconda

```
%%bash
MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT=Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
MINICONDA_PREFIX=/usr/local
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/$MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT
chmod +x $MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT
./$MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT -b -f -p $MINICONDA_PREFIX

import sys
_ = (sys.path
        .append("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"))
```

and then

```
!conda install  pytorch==1.0.0 torchvision==0.2.1 cuda100 -c pytorch --yes
```

but when i

```
import torch
torch.__version__
```

it's 1.9+cuda120

what's more, when i trying to

```
pip uninstall torch
```

colab told me that do you want to uninstall pytorch-1.0.0

how does it happen?

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to run

```
!pip uninstall torch -y
```

The `-y` is for skipping the prompt request. This will uninstall `torch`, it will take more or less 5 minutes.

Then, you have to

```
!pip install torch==1.0.0
```

And finally

```
import torch
torch.__version__
# '1.0.0'
```

Comment: Just use `!pip uninstall torch -y` to skip the confirmation prompt.